# values missing while inserting geojson values to postgres table

Tags: python, postgresql, gis, geojson

I am trying to read a geojson file and insert the records into a postgres table - using the below python code.

```
import json
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="<<ip_address>>",database="DB1", user="<<id>>", password="pwd")
cur = conn.cursor()
with open('NTA_shape.json') as f:
Geojson_data = json.load(f)
for feature in Geojson_data['features']:   
    type_val=feature['geometry']['type']
    geom=feature['geometry']['coordinates']
    ntaname=feature['properties']['NTAName']
    boroname=feature['properties']['BoroName']
    data = {"type":type_val,"coordinates":geom}
    sql ="""Insert into <<Table_NAME> (geom,ntaname,boroname) VALUES(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(%s),%s,%s)""" 
    nta_boro=(json.dumps(data),ntaname,boroname)
    cur.execute(sql,nta_boro)
    conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

But when I query the table, lot of records are missing. 
If I print the json.dumps(data) variable - its showing all records.

I am not sure, what am i missing during table insert
Kindly help.

Comment: I was able to fix it with below change                                                                               
    nta_boro=(json.dumps(data,),ntaname,boroname)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix with below change

```
nta_boro=(json.dumps(data,),ntaname,boroname)
```